# Remote machine node unable to connect to hub on Selenium Webdriver using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have been trying to register a node to the hub, but I am getting "couldn't register this node : Hub is down or not responding".

But I already started the hub. I can see hub started from

```
<http://localhost:4444/grid/console>

C:\Ruby200>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub -port 4444
10:45:37.304 INFO - Launching a selenium grid server
2014-10-24 10:45:38.324:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2014-10-24 10:45:38.363:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContext
Handler{/,null}
2014-10-24 10:45:38.375:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.
0.0:4444
```

On the node (which is a remote machine which I am accessing from remote desktop connection), I tried the following:

```
c:\Ruby201>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role node -hub http://<ip address ofhub>:4444/grid/register
```

I tried different methods (after searching on google and this website) but all of them giving same error..coulnd't connect to the hub

I tried :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://<ip of hub>:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://<ip of hub>:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS -hubHost "ip address of hub"
```

If my node is on same machine as hub, then it is working. But not if node is on remote machine.  Should I be checking for something else like firewalls on node or hub or anything else?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out after few more searches:

Started the hub (on local machine):
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar  -role hub`

Started the node (on remote machine):
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role node -hub`    `http://ipofhub:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Ruby21\bin\chromedriver.exe"`

I had to specify the path of chromedriver while starting the server. I defined in the PATH on remote machine, but only the above method worked.

I have the following code in the test script that I executed from local machine:
`caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "<http://localhost:4444/wd/hub>",:desired_capabilities => caps)`